# OpenSceneGraph - How to detect two Node are intersect with each other?

Tags: openscenegraph

Im tring to make a collision between two nodes in OpenSceneGraph. I want to make a way to ensure that two nodes are intersect. how to do that. Im showing as follows my function to detect the collision.

```
void movetruck(osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> land, osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> truck, osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> ob1, osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> ob2)
{
    osg::Vec3d trPos = truck->getPosition();


    if ("must be true if both ob1 and ob2 are intersected")
    {
        trPos[2] += 0.01;
    }else{
        trPos[0] += 0.01;
    }
    truck->setPosition(trPos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenSceneGraph has `BoundingSphere`and `BoundingBox`. The latter is only used for `Geometry` nodes (unless you implement a bit yourself), so the `BoundingSphere` is the easiest way. This will not give you a correct intersection of the model, but between two spheres, that each are centered at the models center and have a radius such that the sphere encompasses exactly all of the model (/subgraph). i.e. If you center of the model is (0, 0, 0) and the point furthes away is (1, 1, 1), then the radius would be exactly `sqrt(3)`.

You can query the `BoundingSphere` of a node by calling `getBound()` and you can query the intersection of two spheres by calling `intersects` on one of the spheres and using the other as the parameter.

In your case it would be like this

```
if(ob1->getBound().intersects(ob2->getBound()))
{
    trPos[2] += 0.01;
}
```